# All Unequal Subsets of Sorted String in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring, subset, combinations

I would like to find all subsets of a sorted string, disregarding order and which characters are next to each other. I think the best way for this to be explained is though an example. The results should also be from longest to shortest.

These are the results for `bell`.

```
bell
bel
bll
ell
be
bl
el
ll
b
e
l
```

I have thought of ways to do this, but none for any length of input.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify your question, since "bell" has to "l"s, would you want "bl" to appear twice or should duplicates be removed ? You have duplicates removed but I wanted to confirm it is intentional.

Comment: Also where is `ll`?

Comment: @steveb This is intentional, duplicated should be removed.

Comment: @miradulo This was unintentional, I fixed it.

Comment: @miradulo, I think there's a subtle difference to dup you've marked. I believe user wants original order of string maintained. It's trivially done, but just thought I'd point it out (as in my answer).

Comment: @jpp That's fair actually, agreed, changes the question a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are generally two ways to approach such things:  generate "everything" and weed out duplicates later, or create custom algorithms to avoid generating duplicates to begin with.  The former is almost always easier, so that's what I'll show here:

```
def gensubsets(s):
    import itertools
    for n in reversed(range(1, len(s)+1)):
        seen = set()
        for x in itertools.combinations(s, n):
            if x not in seen:
                seen.add(x)
                yield "".join(x)

for x in gensubsets("bell"):
    print(x)
```

That prints precisely what you said you wanted, and how it does so should be more-than-less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `itertools.combinations`.

If the order for strings of same length is important, see [@TimPeters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343794/9209546).

```
from itertools import combinations

mystr = 'bell'

res = sorted({''.join(sorted(x, key=lambda j: mystr.index(j)))
             for i in range(1, len(mystr)+1) for x in combinations(mystr, i)},
             key=lambda k: -len(k))

# ['bell', 'ell', 'bel', 'bll', 'be', 'll', 'bl', 'el', 'l', 'e', 'b']
```

**Explanation**

- Find all combinations of length in `range(1, len(mystr)+1)`.
- Sort by original string via `key` argument of `sorted`. *This step may be omitted if not required.*
- Use set of `''.join` on elements for unique strings.
- Outer `sorted` call to go from largest to smallest.

Comment: I think you want `len(mystr)+1` to not miss `'bell'`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try in one line:

```
import itertools

data='bell'

print(set(["".join(i) for t in range(len(data)) for i in itertools.combinations(data,r=t) if "".join(i)!='']))
```

output:

```
{'bel', 'bll', 'ell', 'el', 'be', 'bl', 'e', 'b', 'l', 'll'}
```